# How to create a dynamic PDF document with PHP, Bootstrap and MySQL

Tags: php, forms, pdf, dynamic, populate

I am struggling to find any info on this.  What I would like to do is have a document which is essentially a template.  After completing various questions, I need the document to update according to what questions were answered.

It will not be difficult to complete the form and send that data to a DB, however, I am not sure what the best/quickest method is to get that data and dynamically build the template in a PDF document.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a few libraries that can do the job (using only your HTML + CSS). But it's strongly recommended to use the template creator from a library. I can recommend [TCPDF](https://packagist.org/packages/tecnickcom/tcpdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DOMpdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) which is an excellent tool for generating pdf files based on the DOM of your page.

There's also [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) I've used it for develop an invoice project. Some developers agree that it's simple to understand.

I recommend you FPDF for its straightforwardness. Also you could check [this form filling with FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php).

Comment: Thank you so much @Arturo. FPDF is exactly what I needed and it is working perfectly.  Much appreciated.